# Showing "select list" under certain circumstances

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to implement an ID list which should only be visible under certain circumstances.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I've got a Radio Group and want the ID list just to appear when the user is selecting 'YES' in the group.

Is there a way to do so?

Greetings and thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dynamic Action.

- Event = Change
- Selection Type = Item(s)
- Item(s) = (your "Merge" radio item)
- Condition = equal to
- Value = YES

True Action = Show

- Selection Type = Item(s)
- Item(s) = (your "Id List" item)
- Fire On Page Load = Yes

False Action = Hide

- Selection Type = Item(s)
- Item(s) = (your "Id List" item)
- Fire On Page Load = Yes